# PCB layout review and controlling ULN2003A

Tags: pcb-design, esp8266, uln2003

I just finished my PCB layout for a relay board, and I would like to ask for some feedback. I'm a beginner in this so any tips will be appreciated.

I also wanted to ask  if the 74HC14 is a good pick for my purpose in combination with ULN2003A. My idea is to send LOW signal from the PCF8575 to the 74HC14 from which a HIGH signal will be sended to the ULN2003A which triggers the relay.

Here is the schematic:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The PCF8575 has an internal POR that may not be 100% reliable under all conditions of external power switching. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Why do people keep insisting on drawing schematics like this? Completely impossible to quickly glance over and get a feeling for what is what and how it works. You should always aim at having a schematic readable from left to right, instead of searching for labels all over the place.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I'm not sure what that means. Could you clarify it to me please?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny I thought it was organized well and readable. Will try to work on that :)

Comment: Check the datasheet under "Power-on Reset" and see if you can guaranteed the conditions they specify. For example, if power blips and does not turn off completely, the chip might not be reset properly. If not, could something like random relay actuation until the MCU catches up (assuming *that* got reset properly) cause you any issues.

Comment: Your diagram is bad. Setting stuff out in little individual blocks and relying on nest-list names to figure out what connects to what is undoubtedly something that you should learn to avoid on circuits as apparently trivial as this. Use connection wires (and name nets if needed) so, if you want review advice, change it.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny It's a stylistic thing and may work better for complex and mostly digital schematics. I don't use it but I don't understand the visceral dislike.

Comment: @Andyaka I have edited the diagram. I hope it's more clear to read now.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How can I prevent this from happening? I see there is some voltage rise times in the datasheet, but I don't really understand it.

Comment: There are errors in your much improved schematic. Well done for making the changes. Look at the net names on the left of the PCF chip and look at C6.

Comment: It's not simple. You could consider including a supervisory reset chip for the ESP so at least that will have a reliable reset. You could just include the footprint on the PCB and leave it barren should it prove to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Andyaka Oh yeah I see the C6, I fixed it thanks. But not sure what do you mean with the net names. I can't find the error there.

Comment: Look at U7 and all the net names to the left.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Okay, I have included it and updated the schematic and the pcb in the post.

Comment: @Andyaka I still can't see the issue, I'm sorry. I don't know exactly what you mean, but the route names are under the traces on the left side, so maybe that's confusing you.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM803_809_810.pdf